# C# application receives data from php

Tags: c#, php

I wanna receive The ***Received Successfully*** message from php but instead i receive the page source!

**C# Code**

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                NameValueCollection students = new NameValueCollection();
                {
                    students.Add("sID", "6");
                    students.Add("sName", "anas");
                    students.Add("sMajor", "prog");
                    String response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(wc.UploadValues(url, students));
                    students.Clear();
                }

            }
```

**PHP Code**

```
if(isset($_POST['sID']) && isset($_POST['sName']) && isset($_POST['sMajor']))
{
    echo "Received Successfully";

    $stID = $_POST['sID'];
    $stName = $_POST['sName'];
    $stMajor = $_POST['sMajor'];
    $insertQuery = "insert into myTable (ID,stName,stMajor) values ('".$stID."','".$stName."','".$stMajor."')";
    $InsertQ   = mysqli_query($Connection, $insertQuery);

}
```

Comment: It's better to use [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

Comment: What do you actually receive? Please give us more informations.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code after replacing your URL

```
    public static string GetResponseFromServer()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("sID", "6"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("sName", "anas"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("sMajor", "prog"),
            });
            var result = client.PostAsync("Your URL Goes here", content);
            string resultContent = result.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return resultContent;
        }
    }
```